Can a single carrier see both IMEI 1 and IMEI 2 in a dual-SIM phone?
I know that a mobile operator sees the IMEI of the SIM slot in which their SIM card is inserted and can see the logs of all the phone numbers associated with that IMEI.
But can they see the IMEI of the other SIM slot if it has a SIM card from a different carrier or none at all?
Any insights or technical details will be highly appreciated.

No, they can't.
